# can't add background image for MVC body tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed the MVC project, I want to add my mvc html body tag for background image I have added but not working.

```
<body style="background-image:url('../../img/bgb.jpg');">
```

Comment: are you sure filename & path are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test if your rule is correctly applying or not. 
To do so, try to define a default background-color to your body.

In case the url to your pic is wrong, this should produce a red background :

```
background: red url('../your/path_to_image') center center;
```